# Swiper click event fails on loop back to first slide

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, slider, swiper.js

The Swiper click event does not work when looping back to the first slide. The click handler fails to trigger in the following scenarios:

- When click `>` arrow from last slide `< 4/4 >`
- When click `<` arrow from first slide `< 1/4 >`

Here is a [live demonstration on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-swiper-api-jrhm61?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMySlides.vue).

[image]

---

Below is a code snippet for your reference:

```
  mounted(): void {
    new Swiper(this.$refs.swiper, {
      modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],

      // SwiperOptions
      loop: true,
      loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 4 * SECOND,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      speed: SECOND / 2,
      observer: true,
      observeParents: true,
      parallax: true,
      preventClicks: false,
      preventClicksPropagation: false,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,

      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },

      on: {
        slideChange: (swiper) => {
          this.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex
        },
        touchEnd: (swiper) => {
          this.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex
        },
      },
    })
  }
```

I have thoroughly searched the internet for a [solution](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3050) to this issue but have not been able to find one.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

slideToClickedSlide: true, might not work as expected when looping is enabled.
So, remove slideToClickedSlide: true

Add a custom click event handler to manually handle the click event and slide to the next/previous slide when arrows are clicked.

Javascript

```
mounted(): void {
  const swiper = new Swiper(this.$refs.swiper, {
    modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],

    // SwiperOptions
    loop: true,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 4 * SECOND,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: SECOND / 2,
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    parallax: true,
    preventClicks: false,
    preventClicksPropagation: false,
    centeredSlides: true,

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },

    on: {
      slideChange: (swiper) => {
        this.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex;
      },
      touchEnd: (swiper) => {
        this.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex;
      },
    },
  });

  // Custom click event handler for navigation arrows
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');
  const prevButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');

  if (nextButton && prevButton) {
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      swiper.slideNext();
    });

    prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      swiper.slidePrev();
    });
  }
}
```